# simple redirect with Django REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to do simple redirect processing.
From `/api/v1/piyo/piyopiyo/<id>/` to `/api/v1/hoge/huga/<id>/`

I thought it was possible with RedirectView, but it loops as follows.
Please tell me how to set urls.py.

### urls.py

```py
from rest_framework import routers
from apiv1.views import hoge
from django.urls import include, path

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register('hoge/huga', hoge.HugaViewSet, basename='Huga')
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    # target redirect settings
    re_path(
        'piyo/piyopiyo/.*$',
        RedirectView.as_view( url='hoge/huga')),
]
```

### accessed url

```
1. /api/v1/piyo/piyopiyo/346c7932-e9e3-4735-9729-eb50fa29c466/
2. /api/v1/piyo/piyopiyo/346c7932-e9e3-4735-9729-eb50fa29c466/hoge/huga
3. /api/v1/piyo/piyopiyo/346c7932-e9e3-4735-9729-eb50fa29c466/hoge/hoge/huga
...
10. /api/v1/piyo/piyopiyo/346c7932-e9e3-4735-9729-eb50fa29c466/hoge/hoge/hoge/hoge/hoge/hoge/hoge/hoge/hoge/hoge/huga
```

redurected 10 times. aborting.

### router.urls

```
[<URLPattern '^hoge/huga/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$' [name='HogeHuga-detail']>]
```

Confirmed with `print(router.urls)`.

Comment: Can you include your `router.urls` and `views`

Comment: If you need to use dynamic url parameters to generate the url to redirect to (and are not redirecting to a static url) consider subclassing and implementing the `get_redirect_url` as described in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview

Comment: comment thx. added router.urls. How do I check views ?

Comment: In your `api` view, there will be a file called `views.py`. Maybe you are redirecting a url too many times in the `api.views.hoge`